# Cannot access, ping and remote google cloud (Change Ip Address Protocol)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

In 4 days, I have found a lot of solutions. But none of them is success. 
I asked the experts in justanswer.com, experthelp.com, freelancer.com .v.v but they can't help me.

I hope you help me soon. I would be sincerely grateful, thanks you so much!

(my english is not good, hope you can understand)

/// Information More ///

Project ID
anbangnews-994
Project number
1014672145918

instance anbangnews-1

I changed ip address (internet protocol version 4 TCP/IPV4, NOT automatically ip) in server google cloud ( by remote server) . Then i can't Ping + Access + remote server. So, how i can change ip address automatically when i can't connect and remote Server?

Please view video (1 minute): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lo2BgV72pWQ Thanks you so much!

Information More:
- Network
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxmjqS0_qwAgTWY0d2xBcnRmX0E/view?usp=sharing

P/s: i used google cloud 1 year, all port open, it working good. I think firewall + ip in console.google.com different ip + dns in computer (google cloud, i remoted > manage and change ip + dns in google cloud).
After i changed ip + dns, then i create instance other... It's error too, can't access, can't ping and can't remote instance new, instance old.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report. The YouTube clip was very helpful.

First, ping is disabled by the cloud firewall. Second, clicking the IP address goes to port 80 which is not set up for your new instance. If you want to login to the instance use the RDP button.